# What do "dark current" and "sensitivity" mean for a camera module?

Tags: sensor, low-light, iso, dynamic-range, electronics

I am looking at a camera module to be used for a project which deals in shooting frames in dark areas and night conditions. This is a camera used from a circuit board. I have the following light values and specification given by my supplier.

Dark Current: <1e-/s @25℃

Sensitivity: 5000 e-/(lux • s)

I am not however sure this works in night mode (like night vision using Infrared illuminator LEDs). Could you give an explanation of these terms?

Answer (score 6):

The sensitivity tells you how much signal you're going to get from your camera module for a given light level: specifically, if you expose your module to 1 [lux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux) for 1 second, it will generate 5000 electrons. (There's probably some spectral dependence there which is hopefully covered in more detail in the full datasheet).

The dark current tells you how much noise you're going to get from your camera module - specifically, when not illuminated, it will generate less than 1 electron per second (at 25 °C - again, see the datasheet for temperature dependence).

With these two numbers and knowledge of the light level you're wanting to use that camera in, you can calculate what signal:noise ratio you're going to get and then work out if that's acceptable for your application or not.